# Tensorflow crop with black filling

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have image ( gray or RGB ), for example:

```
x1y1, x2y1, x3y1, x4y1, x5y1
x1y2, x2y2, x3y2, x4y2, x5y2
x1y3, x2y3, x3y3, x4y3, x5y3
x1y4, x2y4, x3y4, x4y4, x5y4
x1y5, x2y5, x3y5, x4y5, x5y5
```

And I need crop function, if crop input is (x, y, w, h) values (-1, -1, 3, 3) and output must be like this:

```
0, 0, 0
0, x1y1, x2y1
0, x1y2, x2y2
```

It is like crop_to_bounding_box, but with black filling

Comment: Did you look at [`tf.image.crop_and_resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize)

Comment: Yeah, it works!

Answer (score 0):

> Did you look at `tf.image.crop_and_resize`

[Lescurel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7370153/lescurel) thank you so much! It works

Comment: Glad that I could help. Consider improving your answer with a code sample, and maybe one or two lines of explanation.

Comment: You can create your answer, and I mark it as solve of problem. Thx you